# Command to get the corrupted jar files in windows

Tags: java, apache, maven

I setup a new maven project and installed all the dependencies that is required but while running the application I am getting the below error.

**java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)**

It might coming because of some jar files are corrupted in the .m2/repository folder.
How can I get that corrupted files and install again the same.

Comment: you can try deleting the jar folder in your `.m2/repository`. This will force maven to redownload the files.

Answer (score 0):

if you have cigwin or another linux shell on your windows you can use `unzip -t *.jar` in you .m2/repository folder so you can see which zip is corrupt